# Table default property change with css grid

Tags: html, css

In my project I have a lot of tabular data tables. I was wondering is it ok to change default table properties to css grid ?
I want to make table more responsive with css grid

`

```
<html>
    <body>
         <table style="display:grid">
              <thead style="display:grid">
                  <tr style="display:grid">
                      <td></td>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: The semantics will be OK. What I'm wondering about is if the browsers won't get confused when you use the grid equivalence of rowspan or colspan on a td rather than the attributes. Test carefully with all browsers.

Comment: got it thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should work. I myself have never done it, but the following is a good link to look over some of the basics if you haven't already: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp. It never can hurt to try.

Comment: it works fine :) I am concerned about semantics of table. If i keep the table structure, will it break down for engines. [link] https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/03/02/a-grid-solution-for-the-responsive-tables-problem/ in this article Rachel Andrew talks about it, just wanted to ask more people about it ;)

Comment: Not sure about the engines. The article was good though. I will definitely have to experiment with tables and grids more. I have never tried the table combined with the grid like you are showing. Sorry I couldn't help more :/

Comment: xexe np :) i can tell that it works pretty good :) with css grid now we can think outside the box :) and do some interesting stuff :)